# REGEX Match integers 6 through 10

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I want to find integers any integers between 6 and 10. I've tried:

```
[6-10]{1,2}
```

but this throws a mysql error (this is for a mysql query). How do you match numbers between 6 and 10?

Comment: Regexes are not a magic tool that you throw at every programming problem.  They are good for finding patterns in strings.  Comparing numeric values has nothing to do with string patterns.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

why complicate your syntax? couldn't it be as simple as this? Using `BETWEEN`,

```
SELECT...
FROM..
WHERE columnName BETWEEN 6 AND 10
```

but anyway if you have other use, you can use `REGEXP` in MySQL

```
where columName REGEXP '10|[6-9]'
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f6fe/3)